# css выбрать нечетные span среди divов

Tags: css, css-selectors

Есть сколько-то div с внутренним span

```
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
```

как выбрать каждый нечетный span?

кроме варианта `div:nth-child(odd) span`, есть более прямой, лучший способ выбора?

Comment: `:nth-child(2n+1)`?

Comment: а почему вариант div:nth-child(odd) span не подходит?

Comment: @soledar10
я надеялся, что, например, `span:nth-of-type(even)` выберет что нужно, в любой глубине. Т.е. к div здесь (в данном случае) обращаться не нужно. Но nth-of-type почему-то не работает здесь...

Comment: @CodeGust, `nth` применяет стили к списку элементов, которые находятся на одном уровне. Нельзя применить `nth` к элементам, которые находятся в разных родителях.

Comment: @Yuri
ну вот... а я и надеялся, что как-то так можно - было бы короче и проще...
Спасибо.

Comment: @CodeGust, ага :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант:

```css
div:nth-child(2n+1) span {color: red}
```

```html
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
<div><span>++</span></div>
```

Других, более "прямых" нету

Comment: Может всё-таки `div span:nth-child(2n+1)`?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, тогда выделятся все span. `:nth-child` обозначает, к какому элементу из списка применить стиль

Comment: гоню беса, не заметил, что каждый спан в отдельном диве )

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, бывает :)

Answer (score -3):

Фактически CSS позволяет не только разрешить четные/нечетные альтернативы, но и произвольные интервалы. Ключевые слова 'even' (четный) и 'odd' (нечетный) являются просто удобными условными обозначениями. Например, для длинного списка рекомендуется сделать следующее:
li:nth-child(5n+3) {font-weight: bold}
Это говорит о том, что каждый 5й список пустой, начиная с 3го. Другим словами, пункты под номерами 3, 8, 13, 18, 23 и т.д. будут пустыми.
ЧЕТНЫЕ И НЕЧЕТНЫЕ КОЛОНКИ

То же самое действует для колонок таблицы, но для этого нужен элемент в документе, который соответствует колонке. Для этого HTML обеспечивает COL. Таблица должна начинаться с одного COL для каждой колонки:

```
<table>
<col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col>
<tr><th>Month<th>1994<th>1995<th>1996...
```

(COL может использоваться для других вещей, кроме стилей, но в этом случае все что нам нужно, чтобы присутствовали COL элементы.)

---

(с) [Оригинал](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.html) [Перевод](http://www.indeep76.com/Style/Example007/evenodd.html)

Comment: Это вы к чему?)

Comment: http://www.indeep76.com/Style/Example007/evenodd.html - копипаста дэтэктэд